# Manipulating records returned in an active record scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

**TLDR**: Is there a way to define a scope such that I can manipulate the records found by a query that uses that scope before it is returned? Can I use the data returned by the query to prepopulate arbitrary values on the collection of records, much like rails can "preload" association data?

Basically I've got a database table holding hierarchical information, so each row has a parent, and there are lots of times I have to chain my way up and down the hierarchy to get a nodes parents or children. To improve performance we're making heavy use of Postgresql's WITH RECURSIVE query which let's us quickly grab all decedents of a given set of node ids. On my actual model, I have two key methods which use this kind of query: an instance method `descendants` and a scope `find_with_all_descendants(*ids)`. However, if I have a collection of these models and I want to loop through and get the descendants for each by calling `descendants` I end up generating a query for each record. So my current code looks like this

```
collection = Node.find_with_all_descendants(1,2,3,4)

# collection gets passed around to other parts of the program ...

collection.each do |node|
  # other parts of the program do stuff with node.descendants, resulting in    
  # a select N+1 issue as the query for descendants fires

  node.descendants
end
```

What would be great would be if I could call `Node.find_with_all_descendants(*ids)` and then prepoluate the descendants collection, so subsequent calls to `descendants` for any of the returned records hits the cached data, rather than resulting in another query. So my `Node.descendants` method might look like this.

```
def descendants
  return @cached_descendants if @cached_descendants
  # otherwise execute big sql statement I'm not including 
end
```

Then I just need to find a place where I can set `@cached_descendants` for records being returned by queries that are using `find_with_all_descendants`

But given this is a scope, and all I can return is an active record association, I'm not clear how I could go about setting this cached value. Is there any sort of hook where I can run code after any queries that use my `find_with_all_descendants` scope return their records?

**UPDATE:** Including the relevant methods by request. Also including some monkey patching magic we use to load the depth and path of the nodes for completeness sake.

```
scope :find_with_all_descendants, -> (*ids) do
  tree_sql =  <<-SQL
    WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path, depth) AS (
        SELECT id, ARRAY[id], 1
        FROM #{table_name}
        WHERE #{table_name}.id IN(#{ids.join(', ')})
      UNION ALL
        SELECT #{table_name}.id, path || #{table_name}.id, depth + 1
        FROM search_tree
        JOIN #{table_name} ON #{table_name}.parent_id = search_tree.id
        WHERE NOT #{table_name}.id = ANY(path)
    )
    SELECT id, depth, path FROM search_tree ORDER BY path
  SQL

  if ids.any?
    rel = select("*")
      .joins("JOIN (#{tree_sql}) tree ON tree.id = #{table_name}.id")
      .send(:extend, NodeRelationMethods)
  else
    Node.none
  end
end

def descendants
  self.class.find_with_all_descendants(self.id).where.not(id: self.id)
end

# This defines the methods we're going to monkey patch into the relation returned by
# find_with_all_descendants so that we can get the path and the depth of nodes
module NodeRelationMethods
  # All nodes found by original ids will have a depth of 1
  # depth is accessible by calling node.depth
  def with_depth
    # Because rails is a magical fairy unicorn, just adding this select statement
    # automatically adds the depth attribute to the data nodes returned by this
    # scope
    select("tree.depth as depth")
  end

  def with_path
    # Because rails is a magical fairy unicorn, just adding this select statement
    # automatically adds the path attribute to the data nodes returned by this
    # scope
    self.select("tree.path as path")
  end
end
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have an instance method working to retrieve `descendants` but you'd like to retrieve all descendants for an arbitrary collection of records? You can likely do this in a SQL call, but you'll need to include the actual SQL code for the instance method `descendants` so we know what kind of logic is involved.

Comment: No, I have both a working instance method and a working scope. I just edited the question for clarity. Let me know if the edit helps. I can post the working sql for both but it's fairly large, and I don't think it's actually relevant to what I'm really trying to ask

Comment: Another way to think of it, is that I'm trying to implement something like the rails "preload" functionality for this arbitrary collection method that is not backed by has_many :association

Comment: I quickly tried modifying `select` to preload but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way you could refactor the descendant relation to leverage `has_many`?  or, depending on what you do with each nodes' descendants, can you do it in an UPDATE ALL in SQL? Since AR doesn't play well with custom SQL, you have to rely on tricks to get it to fit within AR's "supported" SQL, so unfortunately, it is difficult to help without seeing the actual SQL. Can you at least post the core logic of the query, if not the whole query?

Comment: I posted the definitions for the methods I've been referencing, including the sql. I'm not sure if I could force descendants to be an association, particularly because it's unclear how I would want `node.descendants << Node.new` and related things to behave. Basically anything related to writing or modifying the association doesn't make sense, because of the hierarchical nature.

Comment: An association would not work in this case; I think the recursive query is the right way to go about this. Did my answer solve N+1 issue you were trying to avoid? or is it missing some functionality you need?

Comment: Sorry got side tracked by some other things and this fell onto the back burner. I'll take a look in the next day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this can be done by overriding http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/exec_queries. Here's some sample code boiled down to the bare esseentials

```
scope :find_with_all_descendants, -> (*ids) do
  #load all your records here...
  where(#...).extend(IncludeDescendants)
end

module IncludeDescendants

  def exec_queries
    records = super
    records.each do |r|
      #pre-populate/manipulate records here before returning
    end
  end 

end
```

Basically rails calls Relation#exec_queries right before the records are returned. By extending the relation we return in our scope, we can override exec_queries. In the overriden method, we get the original method results, manipulate them further and then return

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `path[1]` to the select, you should be able to use Ruby's `group_by` (*not* AR `group`, which is for SQL `GROUP BY`) to group the selected records by the top-level parent ID. I've written an example of this below, with some refactoring of the scope to take advantage of chained scopes:

```
def self.all_descendants
  tree_sql =  <<-SQL
    WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path, depth) AS (
        SELECT id, ARRAY[id], 1
        FROM (#{where("1=1").to_sql}) tmp
      UNION ALL
        SELECT #{table_name}.id, path || #{table_name}.id, depth + 1
        FROM search_tree
        JOIN #{table_name} ON #{table_name}.parent_id = search_tree.id
        WHERE NOT (#{table_name}.id = ANY(path))
    )
    SELECT id, depth, path FROM search_tree ORDER BY path
  SQL
  unscoped.select("*, tree.depth as depth, tree.path as path, tree.path[1] AS top_parent_id")
    .joins("JOIN (#{tree_sql}) tree ON tree.id = #{table_name}.id")
end

def descendants
  self.class.where(id: id).all_descendants.where.not(id: id)
end
```

This way, you can do the following:

```
collection = Node.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).all_descendants
collection.group_by(&:top_parent_id).each do |top_parent_id, descendant_group|
  top_parent = descendant_group.detect{|n| n.id == top_parent_id}
  top_parent_descendants = descendant_group - top_parent
  # do stuff with top_parent_descendants
end
```

Comment: This is good, and I'm going to upvote, but not accept yet because it's not quite what I was trying to accomplish. I think I've found away to more closely mimic the built in preload by overiding http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/exec_queries. I'm going to test that and may then post it as an answer to my own question

Answer (score 0):

This is very far past the point you needed it, but I'm faced with a very similar problem, and I'm wondering if the recursive query gem was looked at, or if it was available at the time, and if it would suit your needs in this case?  I'm hoping not to monkey-patch a core class, nor ideally to override a method in ActiveRecord, but this seems to be a solid DSL-style extension to address what I should think is a decently common issue:

https://github.com/take-five/activerecord-hierarchical_query